# Mock SQLServer CallableStatement

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following unit test, in which I want to test that the statement is called with the correct parameters in the correct order.

```
    StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("Schema.Procedure(?,?,?)");
    CloseableSQLServerDataTable table = new CloseableSQLServerDataTable(new SQLServerDataTableFactory().build());

    Connection conn = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    SQLServerCallableStatement stmt  = Mockito.mock(SQLServerCallableStatement.class);
    when(conn.prepareCall("{ call Schema.Procedure(?,?,?) }")).thenReturn(stmt);

    sp.executeWithTableParam(conn, table, 1, "Schema.CustomType", "foo", true);

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(stmt);
    inOrder.verify(stmt).setObject(1, "foo");
    inOrder.verify(stmt).setObject(2, table);
    inOrder.verify(stmt).setObject(3, true);
    inOrder.verify(stmt).execute();
```

The method `executeWithTableParam` simply gets the statement and does the set of the parameters in the right order.

Here is a snipet:

```
    try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(call))
    {
        setParametersWithTable(stmt, tableData, tableParamIndex, tableDataType, parameters);
        stmt.execute();
    }
```

And finally the `setParametersWithTable` method

```
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if (index < tableParamIndex)
        {
            stmt.setObject(index + 1, parameters[index + 1]);
        }
        else if (index == tableParamIndex)
        {
            ((SQLServerCallableStatement) stmt).setStructured(tableParamIndex + 1 , tableDataType, tableData.getWrapped());
        }
        else
        {
            stmt.setObject(index + 1, parameters[index + 1]);
        }

    }
}
```

My question is, **why do I get a NullPointerException at the setMethod?** The code in the SQLServerStatement class shouldn't be executed because that's the point of mocking

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.checkClosed(SQLServerStatement.java:1046)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1487)
at com.xxx.yyy.StoredProcedure.setParametersWithTable(StoredProcedure.java:225)
```

Relevant versions:

1. Mockito 1.10.19
2. JDBC 7.0.0
3. JDK 1.8.0_151

Comment: What does it do if you accept any string like; `when(conn.prepareCall(anyString())).thenReturn(stmt);`

Comment: did you found a solution? facing similar issue.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha, getting a null pointer exception when calling when(conn.prepareCall(anyString())).thenReturn(stmt);